# Open an aspx page as a modal popup on button click from another aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopup

I have two web pages Home.aspx and Details.aspx.
In Home.aspx, I have a table with few contents and one of the column is a link button. On this button click, I'm directing the page to Details.aspx using `Response.Redirect("Details.aspx")` and also passing some values using `commandArgument`

```
<td><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" 
                            runat="server" 
                            Text='<% # Eval("Count") %>' 
                            CausesValidation="false"
                            commandArgument='<%#Eval("title")+","+ Eval("Count") %>'
                            OnCommand="LinkButton1_Click"/>
                    </td>

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] commandArgs = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
            string title = commandArgs[0];
            Session["title"] = title;
            string count= commandArgs[1];

            Response.Redirect(string.Format("Details.aspx?title={0}&count={1}", title, count), false);

        }
```

In Details.aspx, on page load, with these session details, im performing some operation which gives me a list of values and using these values im generating a `repeater`.

Details.aspx page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                string conTitle = (string) Session["title"];

                List <string> myTitleList = (List<string>) Session["docTitles"];
                List<List<string>> myTitleContentList = (List<List<string>>)Session["content"];

                int i = myTitleList.IndexOf(conTitle); 
                try
                {
                    List<string> displayList = myTitleContentList[i];
                    cdcatalog.DataSource = displayList;
                    cdcatalog.DataBind();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Now I want to do all this on a modal popup instead of Response.Redirect.
Is it possible to load an aspx page as a modal popup on button click.

Comment: Change your response.redirect to call a javascript function which open a new window dialog.

Comment: but my suggestion is to use ajaxtoolkit for asp.net. http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Comment: @Dr.Stitch If I use ajax tool kit , where should I write the page load content of Details.aspx page. because I saw few examples where in they just used a panel to displayed a label in it.But There is no example of doing some operation. Can you help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use ModalPopUp from Ajax Control [Toolkit](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)

> The ModalPopup extender allows a page to display content to the user
>   in a "modal" manner which prevents the user from interacting with the
>   rest of the page. The modal content can be any hierarchy of controls
>   and is displayed above a background that can have a custom style
>   applied to it.

2. You can use place the content in a div and open the Pop-Up using [Jquery](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form).

> Use a modal dialog to require that the user enter data during a
>   multi-step process. Embed form markup in the content area, set the
>   modal option to true, and specify primary and secondary user actions
>   with the buttons option.

Comment: If I use ajax tool kit , where should I write the page load content of Details.aspx page. because I saw few examples where in they just used a panel to displayed a label in it.But There is no example of doing some operation. Can you help me with this.

Comment: You can convert the Details page to a user Control and then access it.

Comment: Any example/tutorial for changing the code to user Control?

Comment: The toolkit link is dead